docker multiplatform image pushed successfully to ghcr but pulling image results in manifest not found
I'm building mutliplatform docker images in github actions. workflow completes successfully, but when I try to pull image from ghcr it results in no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries. I've not tried pulling image on arm architecture as I don't have a system available.
My workflow file:
name: Build and push image

on:
  push:
    tags: ["*"]

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
      attestations: write
      id-token: write
    strategy:
      matrix:
        platform:
          - linux/amd64
          - linux/arm/v6
          - linux/arm/v7
          - linux/arm64
          - linux/ppc64le
          - linux/riscv64
          - linux/s390x
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          push: true
          platforms: ${{ matrix.platform }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - name: Generate artifact attestation
        uses: actions/attest-build-provenance@v2
        with:
          subject-name: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME}}
          subject-digest: ${{ steps.push.outputs.digest }}
          push-to-registry: true


With the matrix build, you create 7 different platform specific images, push them to the same tag, and the last one to push to the tag is the result. The registry is not merging the various single platform pushes together into a multi-platform image, that's the job of the build tooling.
The easy option that most use is to delete the matrix configuration and leverage the buildx ability to build multiple platform simultaneously:
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          push: true
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/riscv64,linux/s390x
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

Other workflows require that you create the multi-platform manifest after pushing the images individually, but in my experience, that only makes sense when you don't use qemu and instead have dedicated platform specific builders, and cannot use buildx contexts to run the builds on each of those builders.
The documentation at https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/ shows the various methods to build multi-platform images with GitHub Actions.

Hi thankyou for the hint that I was overwriting images. I was able to make it work with examples provided by docker with matrix. Now I've multiplatform images in ghcr, but one of them is displayed as unknown/unknown. Any idea how I can fix this?

@Inder The unknown/unknown entries in the manifest list are Docker's way of shipping build attestations. They can be disabled with --provenance=none on the buildx CLI (or provenance: none in GHA. https://docs.docker.com/build/metadata/attestations/slsa-provenance/
